# How to convert an existing project to a Reproducible Research (RR) project using rstudio and github?

Tags: github, rstudio

## Background

I am a research assistant and master's candidate in Civil Engineering. I began to use R for analyses on large data files when Excel couldn't open them. In the course of my learning I began using rstudio and later got acquainted with the the use of markdown and latex within it. Now I am in the middle of my thesis and have fallen in love with the concept of RR and want to use it for my own research. I've also learned about advantages of Github and setting up repositories, etc.

## Question

I have a lot of individual .R files filled with code, some .tex and .Rmd files for little reports. At some point I created a new rstudio project (for 1 out of 3 given data sets) and now keep all new analyses in that folder. I need your advice as to how can I combine all previous code to one folder (Is doing everything in a single Rmd file wise?) and put this folder to github (I know about creating new repos for new projects but don't know about putting existing project on github). What are the best practices in RR for a master's thesis project?

Later I want to create package(s) and Shiny apps related to my project.

Comment: Most of this is very broad and primarily opinion-based. However, I can tell you about putting existing repositories up on GitHub: Create a new repository as normal, but don't initialize it with a README. After you do this, GitHub will show you the exact procedure for adding an existing repository. It will be something like `git remote add origin git://...`, `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also know that RStudio has a very good integrated function to manage git repositories. E.g. you create a new repository on Github then you copy the SSH key (sth. like git@github.com:username/repositoryname.git), open a new project in RStudio, choose "Version Control" -> "Git"  and enter the SSH Key into as "Repository URL" and click "Create Project".

Now you can copy/paste all your files into your local repository folder. You also can manage the whole commit/push/pull processes of git via RStudio.

Keep in mind that https://bitbucket.org/ offers the possibility for hosting of private repositories, if you want to make the thesis publicly available only when it is finished.